# Escape to html within class

Tags: javascript, php, class

Here's an interesting picture of some PHP code that I saw:

[image]

What interests me is the use of

```
<?php echo $this->id; ?>
```

How can that work? To the best of my knowledge it is impossible to use ?> mid-class to break out to html, and you can't reassign the $this keyword.

What's going on?

**Edit:** The 'doge' text was not added by me. That's simply how the picture was when I found it.

Comment: 1) Can't see <expletive> with your punny doge text scrawled all over. 2) You *can* break in and out of PHP inside a class without any problem.

Comment: I didn't add that text. That is how the picture was. Can you give a working example of breaking out of a class and using the this keyword? I can't seem to make it work myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly just guessing here, because it's impossible to see anything in the provided sample, but most likely you're looking at this:

file_a.php

```
<html>
    ...
    <?php echo $this->id; ?>
    ...
</html>
```

file_b.php

```
class Foo {

    public $id = 42;

    public function bar() {
        include 'file_a.php';
    }

}
```

Yes, that works.

So does this:

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public $id = 42;

    public function bar() {
?>
<html>
    <?php echo $this->id; ?>
</html>
<?php
    }
}
```

Not that that's a great idea, but it works. Because it's not "breaking out of the class", it's *breaking in and out of PHP interpreter mode*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see how that is impossible. That really depends on what context you are in. For example, see/use https://github.com/DeathsEffigy/Pikatchp which is a very basic framework that i started working on. Inside the templates you are able to use $this->my_set_var as well.